# Problem with PrimeFaces taglib in using JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I downloaded and added `primefaces-3.0.M1.jar` file to my project.
Then, I added this code to my JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" prefix="p" %>
```

But it gives the error:

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"

Can anyone guide me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: The taglib descriptor looks fine. Where did you put the jar file?

Comment: i added jar file in Build Path as external Archive, i also check by adding jar file in lib folder under web-inf

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, format every line of code by **four spaces**. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the primefaces forum there are [some comments](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6715) that Primefaces 2.x and above won't work with JSP. Use Facelets instead.

A facelet page using primefaces looks like this:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
      <h:head>
        ... put your header info here
      </h:ead>
      <h:body>
        .. put your content here
      </h:body>
    </html>
```

There are some more things to pay attention to if you want to switch from jsp to facelets. I think you start reading [some tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipob.html) or this [related question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0).

Comment: On glassfish3 facelets must have a .xhtml not .html extension to be recognized as those.

Answer (score -2):

You could try the following workaround:

```
<% response.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml"); %>
```

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, indent every line of code by four spaces. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Doesn't solve the problem at all. 2) MSIE browser doesn't support this content type and will then pop a *Save As* dialogue.

Answer (score -2):

just add `primefaces` to your project buildpath.

[image: primefaces in project buildpath]

Comment: That is true IF you are already using the correct namespace. In this case the namespace was wrong.

Comment: i had the same problem with correct namespace. after i've added primefaces into the buildpath i was able to use p: tag library...

Comment: Yes, that is what I said.. IF you already use the right namespace and you get this error, then this is the answer. But that is **not** what the problem in this question is about. So please add a clarification in the answer. And add info about version etc